# Undefined method `to' for nil:NilClass + devise + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `Devise` in my Rails application. For some users I am getting this kind of error:

`undefined method 'to' for nil:NilClass` from this method

```
def http_auth_header?
 Devise.mappings[scope].to.http_authenticatable && !request.xhr?
end
```

that is from `Devise` itself.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, Did you try to override the current_user method? I had the same error doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I spent time to fix the same issue.

I did some custom stuff into the SessionController :

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => "user", :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
```

And in fact, scope **MUST BE** a symbol :

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
```

So I think you just provide a scope as a String instead of a symbol

Hope it helps ;)